# Boolean Scope Value of a Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say I have a directive which looks like:

```
<foo-bar bar-foo="booleanValue"></foo-bar>
```

`booleanValue` here belongs to the parent scope - the scope of the controller which is attached to the view in which the above directive element is located.

Now, in my directive, I have defined the directive as follows:

```
app.directive('fooBar', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            barFoo: '=barFoo'
        },
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
           scope.$watch('barFoo', function() {
               if(scope.barFoo !== true) return;
           });
           //Code to execute when barFoo is true
        }
    };
});
```

Problem here is that the value that is passed to `barFoo` is a boolean value, but it ends up being a string value. Thus `if (scope.barFoo !== true) will always be a success and the linker function never executes.

I do not want to change the code to `if (scope.barFoo === "true")`.

How do I pass a boolean value into the scope?

**EDIT :** I wish to add here that `booleanValue` is indeed a boolean value (passed as true usually) by the parent controller into the directive. Just that when the value is passed, it gets converted to string instead of remaining boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the value is set properly in the controller, it should be passed as boolean to the directive.

This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yyc9LxJe9e23Q4n60B4L?p=preview) illustrates this.

Comment: Actually the problem was that I had forgotten to remove the `ng-controller` attribute from the element which was assigned to another controller. Thus there were two controllers in total - one from the directive and one from the `ng-controller` attribute - removing the latter fixed the issue. Thanks for letting me know that my issue is indeed a bug in my application and not standard behaviour!